# World chess championship final calendar

Tags: tournament

Is there a way to import World chess championship final match into google calendar?

Can I do that for other major chess events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get an `.ics` file for every major tournament on the broadcast page for that tournament on chess24.com. When you are on that page, click the **Information** tab, then download the file.

[image]

Now open Google Calendar, click the cogwheel icon, and then click **Settings**. On the settings page click **Import & Export**. There is a form where you can select the `.ics` file. Click **Import** to add it to your calendar. And that's all.